# Installing ufw on Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, iptables

I am thinking of installing ufw on my Raspberry Pi that is running Debian Stretch because I am no expert in firewalls and I think it would make my life easier. My understanding is that ufw is just a front end to iptables - correct?.
I already have several rules in my iptables that I have managed to get working (without full understanding!) and do not want to lose them, they allow nfs through, webmin etc.
If I save the existing tables (iptables-save) can I then read them back in using ufw - or will the ufw install respect them anyway?
It will be a bit of a pain if I have to add them again individually.
Thanks
NormB